# Performing Data Analysis on Pivoted DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I'm loading data from a database, and creating a DataFrame,

```
db_resultset = self.result.fetchall()
df = DataFrame(db_resultset)
df.columns = self.result.keys()
pivoted_data = df.pivot(index='id', columns='item')

    data =
    id  item  val
     1    A    10
     2    A    25
     1    B    12
     1    C    15
     2    C    2
     1    D    7
     2    D    9
     ...

    pivoted_data =
         A    B    C    D
    1   10   12   15    7
    2   25   NaN   2    9
    ...
```

And I would like to calculate things like Pairwise Correlation, `pivoted_data.corr()`, which leads to errors such as:

```
File "/.../pandas/core/frame.py", line 4469, in corr
    numeric_df = self._get_numeric_data()
  File "/.../pandas/core/frame.py", line 4989, in _get_numeric_data
    return self.ix[:, []]
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 224, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = retval.ix._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 342, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 408, in _getitem_iterable
    not isinstance(keyarr[0], tuple)):
```

What is the best way to perform analysis on a pivoted set of data? I've thought of converting the `pivoted_data` back to a DataFrame, but this doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

** **EDIT:**

In response to Jeff's comment:

```
pivoted_data.get_dtype_counts() =
object    319
```

Comment: pivoted_data IS a DataFrame, but your data is probably object type, post pivoted_data.get_dtype_counts()

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for the comment. Could you expand on why `object` type is causing the problem, and how I can fix it?

Comment: try pivoted_data.astype('float64'), then do what you need. (you can also specify dtype='float64') on the dataframe construction (note if you have non floatlike then this might break and you will have to do column-by-column)

Comment: object type in numpy is basically a pointer to data, you need float (or int or a 'real') type do really do anything useful. the only object data that is useful are strings

Comment: you might be better off using this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#sql-queries, it does most of the conversions

Comment: Jeff, apologies for the delay. This was the root of the problem. `df['val'] = df['val'].astype('float64')` Post an answer and I can accept, if you'd like. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is reading the rows into the data frame correctly. Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(db_curr.fetchall(),
                               index=["id", "item"],
                               columns=[col_desc[0] for col_desc in db_curr.description])
df = df.unstack()
```

The last line produces the pivoted data.